# Method accept three boolean parameter and return string on bases of these boolean values C#

Tags: c#

I came with a method which accepts three bool parameters and returns a string value. For example, I am saving 0,1,2 in a table column. I have three boolean variables `isView`, `isAddUpdate` and `isDelete`. When `isView` is `true` then save only 0, if `isView` and `isAddUpdate` are true than save 0,1 and if all of them are true than save 0,1,2.

Here is my code. Please suggest me a better approach to achieve this.

```
public string getActions(bool isView, bool isAddupdate, bool isDelete)
{
    try
    {
        var _val = "";
        if (isView && isAddupdate && isDelete)
            _val = "0,1,2";
        if (isView && isAddupdate && !isDelete)
            _val = "0,1";
        if (isView && !isAddupdate && !isDelete)
            _val = "0";
        if (!isView && !isAddupdate && !isDelete)
            _val = "";
        if (!isView && !isAddupdate && isDelete)
            _val = "2";
        if (!isView && isAddupdate && isDelete)
            _val = "1,2";
        return _val;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex; 
    }
}
```

Comment: **First**: does your code *work*? **Second** step should be optimization. Don´t swap those two steps.

Comment: Is `0,2` a possible return value?

Comment: There are 8 possible combinations of three booleans (2 choices each, 2x2x2=8) your code covers 6. Also, if by "I am saving 0,1,2 in table column" you're referring to an *SQL* table, be aware that this is a bad plan too. The way of storing multiple values of the same "logical type" (as distinct from the data type) is to have one column and *multiple* rows.

Comment: **Never** use `catch` -> `throw ex;`. It does _nothing_ except eating your stack trace and thus hiding where the error came from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```cs
public string getActions(bool isView, bool isAddupdate, bool isDelete)
{
    var codes = new List<int>();

    if (isView) codes.Add(0);
    if (isAddupdate) codes.Add(1);
    if (isDelete) codes.Add(2);

    return string.Join(",", codes);
}
```

Comment: Note that in older .Net versions, `String.Join` will only accept an array as second argument, meaning you would need to do `string.Join(",", codes.ToArray());`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string getActions(bool isView, bool isAddupdate, bool isDelete)
{
    string[] values = new string[3];
    if (isView)
        values[0] = "0";
    if (isAddupdate)
        values[1] = "1";
    if (isDelete)
        values[2] = "2";
    return String.Join(",", values.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
}
```

I removed the `try/catch` block. I don't see any reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a different approach but try using [`[Flags]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types) enum

Something like this might help in general

```
[Flags]
. public enum Actions
. {
.   None = 0,
.   View = 1,
.   AddUpdate = 2,
.   Delete = 4
. }
```

Something like this if you wanna stick with bool inputs

```
public string getActions(bool isView, bool isAddUpdate, bool isDelete)
{
    var a = isView ? Actions.View : Actions.None;
    a |= isAddUpdate ? A.AddUpdate : Actions.None;
    a |= isDelete ? Actions.Delete : Actions.None;

    return a.ToString();
}
```

Suppose `isView` is true, `isAddUpdate` is false, and `isDelete` is true, this will return

`"View, Delete"`

Comment: What data type is `A` here?

Comment: Looks like he changed the enum name from `Actions` to `A` in his code. That said, those could be normal `if`s instead of inline ones; doing an OR operation with 0 does nothing anyway. Also, [according to c# specs, the 0 one should be called "None".](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1008-enums-should-have-zero-value)

Comment: By the way, the function still says it's returning a string, while you're returning the Actions enum. You never actually convert it to a string.

Comment: Oh totally sorry, it's `Actions` not `A`
yeah right the code got mixed up with a draft one I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a relational database such as SQL Server, MySql or PostgreSQL then i suggest you store those values as bits as it will be cheaper than storing a 3 character string.

But if you need to do it this way or if you are using something like MongoDB then i propose this solution instead, dont store 1,2,3 store binary characters (1 or 0) to accurately represent boolean values.

See my code below for illustration:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stringvalue = getActions(false, true, false); //this result you store to your db
            Console.WriteLine(stringvalue);
            Console.ReadLine();
            var deserialised = DeserialiseActions(stringvalue); //you would have retrieved this from the database
        }

        public static string getActions(bool isView, bool isAddupdate, bool isDelete)
        {
            return $"{Convert.ToSByte(isView).ToString()}{Convert.ToSByte(isAddupdate).ToString()}{Convert.ToSByte(isDelete).ToString()}";
        }

        public static ActionsCollection DeserialiseActions(string dataValue)
        {
            return new ActionsCollection
            {
                IsView = bool.Parse(dataValue[0].ToString()),
                IsUpdate = bool.Parse(dataValue[1].ToString()),
                IsDelete = bool.Parse(dataValue[2].ToString())
            };
        }
    }

    class ActionsCollection
    {
        public bool IsView { get; set; }
        public bool IsUpdate { get; set; }
        public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
    }
}
```